# Does a compact set with non-empty interior have a limit point?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

**My Question**: Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ open and $K\subset U$ be a compact set with nonempty interior $K^{o}$, then $K$ must have a limit point in $U$.

**Remark:** I think that the statement is true. I know that a non-empty open set  has limit points, then, as $K^{o}$ is non-empty, $K^{o}$ have limit points, then $K$ have limit points. but I do not know if this may serve to prove the statement.

Please tell me who fails in my attempt, if  my attempt is incorrect, then  tell me how I can finish the prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is correct. If $A \subset B$ then every limit point of $A$ is a limit point of $B$ (can you see why?).

Using another argument: it is enough to assume that $K$ is compact and infinite.
Then, there is an infinite sequence $\{ z_n \}_n \subset K$ made up of distinct terms. By compactness of $K$, this sequence has a convergent subsequence to a point $z \in K$: this is a limit point of $K$.

Answer (score 0):

every infinite sequence in a compact set has subsequence which is convergent in it.
and K is a subset proper subset of U therefore K has a limit point in U